# How to make databinding with MutableLiveData<Boolean> and button with android:enabled?

Tags: android, data-binding

I have a registration form where I have a big condition to continue. For simplicity, I have an `editText` and a `Button`. I write with MVVM so I have a `ViewModel()` where
`val stroke = MutableLiveData<String>()`
is stored. So when stroke length is more than 5 the button has to be activated. I do it like this:
Activity
'class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)


    binding.model = viewModel

}}
```

View Model

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel(){
val stroke = MutableLiveData<String>()

val enableButton = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    get(){
        field.value = (stroke.value ?: "").length > 5
        return field
    }}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="nekono.inno.mvvmsample.MainViewModel"/>
</data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@={model.stroke}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:enabled="@{model.enableButton}"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

It seems like enabled only asks variable ones, at the moment of binding, after that it stops asking and holds the state that was at the moment of binding. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Transformations on stroke to achieve that.

```
val stroke = MutableLiveData<String>()
val enableButton: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(stroke) {  it.length > 5 }
```

When `stroke` changes also the `enableButton` value will change

Comment: There is nobody checking for changes

Comment: still doesn't work for me with AGP 3.3.1. Probably a bug.

Comment: What's AGP? I running it on the latest version of AS targeting android P without issues.